# Use autoprefixer synchronously

Tags: css, node.js, autoprefixer, postcss

I want to use autoprefixer in my node application to compile css.
For my specific needs, I want to call autoprefixer without callback or promise.

Just plain:

```
var result = autoprefixer.process(css);
```

or

```
var result = myPrefixerWrap(css);
```

I am fighting with this for a while, can you help me please?

ps: I already tried postcss-js, but it result an json object for react use, and not pure css. For example `{borderRadius:"5px"}`

```js
var prefixer    = postcssJs.sync([ autoprefixer ]);
var cssCompiled = postcss.parse(css);
var cssObject   = postcssJS.objectify(cssCompiled);
var autoResult  = prefixer(cssObject);
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using Promises? (Not saying that's not a valid thing to want to do, just curious)

Comment: compiling css its just one step in the way of many things/modules that my application dose, and most of my code is not using promises, i want to make things simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostCSS has an API for synchronously getting the results of `Processor#process` ([`process().css`](http://api.postcss.org/LazyResult.html#css), aliased as `toString()`), which will work as long as all of the PostCSS plugins being used are synchronous (like Autoprefixer). The code to do that is as simple as:

```
var postcss = require('postcss'); // import postcss from 'posts';
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'); // import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
postcss([autoprefixer]).process(styleString).css;
```

---

Note: I had issues with using postcss-js in Webpack, so for those who see errors like:

```
Module parse failed: /path/to/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/caniuse-db/features-json/css-regions.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Or:

```
ERROR in ./~/autoprefixer/~/browserslist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /path/to/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist
 @ ./~/autoprefixer/~/browserslist/index.js 3:14-27
```

Check out the [Troubleshooting section](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-js#troubleshoot) of the postcss-js GitHub readme to find out what you need to add to your Webpack config to get it working.